# css 3D vertical line from the centre of the circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
var radius = 200; // adjust to move out servicesitems in and out 
  var fields = $('.servicesitem'),
  container = $('#servicescontainer'),
  width = container.width(),
  height = container.height();
  var angle = 0,
  step = (2 * Math.PI) / fields.length;
  fields.each(function() {
  var x = Math.round(width / 2 + radius * Math.cos(angle) -     $(this).width() / 2);
  var y = Math.round(height / 2 + radius * Math.sin(angle) - $(this).height() / 2);
  if (window.console) {
    console.log($(this).text(), x, y);
  }
  $(this).css({
    left: x + 'px',
    top: y + 'px'
  });
  angle += step;
});
```

```css
<style>
    .block {
      width:400px;
      height:500px;
 }
.block:before {
      content:"";
      width:3px;
      height:100%;
      display:block;
      position:absolute; 
      left:50%;
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7e348c,  #7e348c,  #7e348c);
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7e348c,  #7e348c,  #7e348c);
      background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #7e348c, #7e348c,  #7e348c);
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #7e348c,  #7e348c, #7e348c);
      background-image: linear-gradient(top, #7e348c,  #7e348c, #7e348c);
 }


ul.members-menu {
 list-style-type: none; 
 margin-left: 0;
 padding-left: 2em;;
 width: 300px;
}

ul.members-menu li a {
  text-decoration:none;
}
ul.members-menu li.active {
  background: #eef;
}
ul.members-menu li:hover {
  background: #eef;
}
#services
{
  width:700px;
  height:700px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.services {
  width: 550px;
  height: 550px;
  border: 5px solid rgba(196, 190, 190, 0.144);
  border-radius: 70%;
  transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(60deg);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #a6a49d 1%, #a6a49d 2%, #a6a49d 30%, #a6a49d 31%, #c4c0b5 100%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  
}


</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="page-section" id="services">
    <div class="container" style="border:2px solid red">
     
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
          <div id="left" style="width:50%;float:left;"> <h2 class="text-center mt-0">Our Services</h2></div>
<div id="right" style="margin-left:50%;">
    <ul class="members-menu">
   <li><a href="#" class="active">Item 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Item 9</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Item 10</a></li>
  </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="block"></div>
          <div class="services">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I am trying to create an illustration just like the below image. I haven't worked with 3D shapes yet. I have tried the above code. Could you please tell me how to point out the line from the centre of the disc and also our services and items are in the side of the line just like in the picture?

Comment: wouldn't this be easier to use some image tool like Adobe to create the picture, and just use the image in your html?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I need to animate the icons and spins the disc when the user scroll down the links

Answer (score 0):

```js
var radius = 200; // adjust to move out servicesitems in and out 
  var fields = $('.servicesitem'),
  container = $('#servicescontainer'),
  width = container.width(),
  height = container.height();
  var angle = 0,
  step = (2 * Math.PI) / fields.length;
  fields.each(function() {
  var x = Math.round(width / 2 + radius * Math.cos(angle) -     $(this).width() / 2);
  var y = Math.round(height / 2 + radius * Math.sin(angle) - $(this).height() / 2);
  if (window.console) {
    console.log($(this).text(), x, y);
  }
  $(this).css({
    left: x + 'px',
    top: y + 'px'
  });
  angle += step;
});
```

```css
<style>
        .block {
          width:400px;
          height:500px;
     }
    .block:before {
        z-index: 9;
          content:"";
          width:3px;
          margin-left:20px;
          height:154%;
          display:block;
          position:absolute; 
          left:50%;
          background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7e348c,  #7e348c,  #7e348c);
          background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7e348c,  #7e348c,  #7e348c);
          background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #7e348c, #7e348c,  #7e348c);
          background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #7e348c,  #7e348c, #7e348c);
          background-image: linear-gradient(top, #7e348c,  #7e348c, #7e348c);
        }
    
    
    ul.members-menu {
     list-style-type: none; 
     margin-left: 0;
     padding-left: 2em;;
     width: 300px;
    }
    
    ul.members-menu li a {
      text-decoration:none;
    }
    ul.members-menu li.active {
      background: #eef;
    }
    ul.members-menu li:hover {
      background: #eef;
    }
    #services
    {
      width:700px;
      height:700px;
      margin:0 auto;
    }
    .services {
      width: 550px;
      height: 550px;
      border: 5px solid rgba(196, 190, 190, 0.144);
      border-radius: 70%;
      transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(60deg);
      background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #a6a49d 1%, #a6a49d 2%, #a6a49d 30%, #a6a49d 31%, #c4c0b5 100%);
      margin: 0 auto;
      
    }
    
    
    </style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <section class="page-section" id="services">
        <div class="container" style="border:2px solid red">
         
          <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
              <div id="left" style="width:50%;float:left;"> <h2 class="text-center mt-0">Our Services</h2></div>
    <div id="right" style="margin-left:50%;">
        <ul class="members-menu">
       <li><a href="#" class="active">Item 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Item 9</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Item 10</a></li>
      </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="block"></div>
              <div class="services">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Added z-index in css . This may help you.Adjust height as you want.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was wondering is there any way I can arrange 'our services' heading and the list items arranged exactly left and right of the straight line?